# Using a class as a look up table

Tags: python

Im looking through the inspect.py module and came across the following code:

```
def getmembers(object, predicate=None):
    """Return all members of an object as (name, value) pairs sorted by name.
    Optionally, only return members that satisfy a given predicate."""
    if isclass(object):
        mro = (object,) + getmro(object)
    else:
        mro = ()
    results = []
    processed = set()
    names = dir(object)
    # :dd any DynamicClassAttributes to the list of names if object is a class;
    # this may result in duplicate entries if, for example, a virtual
    # attribute with the same name as a DynamicClassAttribute exists
    try:
        for base in object.__bases__:
            for k, v in base.__dict__.items():
                if isinstance(v, types.DynamicClassAttribute):
                    names.append(k)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    for key in names:
        # First try to get the value via getattr.  Some descriptors don't
        # like calling their __get__ (see bug #1785), so fall back to
        # looking in the __dict__.
        try:
            value = getattr(object, key)
            # handle the duplicate key
            if key in processed:
                raise AttributeError
        except AttributeError:
            for base in mro:
                if key in base.__dict__:
                    value = base.__dict__[key]
                    break
            else:
                # could be a (currently) missing slot member, or a buggy
                # __dir__; discard and move on
                continue
        if not predicate or predicate(value):
            results.append((key, value))
        processed.add(key)
    results.sort(key=lambda pair: pair[0])
    return results
```

It seems as if they have used the `set` class as a method name storage, that is later used as a lookup from the line `if key in processed:`.

Are there any advantages to looking up method names in a `set`, as compared to other data structures like `list`s or `dict`s?

Comment: The `set` type is built in, and there certainly is not an implementation [in `inspect.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/inspect.py). What you are probably looking at is some kind of stub file generated automatically by your IDE, for documentation purposes (so that "Go to Definition..." or similar will work).

Comment: That said, yes, `set` is the appropriate data type for this kind of check. If you want to understand what they are and/or how they work, please start [with the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=set#sets).

Comment: Yes, that's the class "definition" found in `builtins.pyi` to provide type hints for the built-in `set` type (which is defined in C, not Python).

Comment: More importantly: it is not "the set class" that is being used as a lookup, but *a set*; i.e. an *instance of* that class. Just like how if you write `a = int('1')`, then `a` is not "the integer class", but an actual integer value.

Comment: @chepner so processed = set() creates a built in set? How does the set class interface help? And why is it used?

Comment: It is used only to provide type hints for the type methods. Notice that the definition provides *only* method signatures, not implementations of those methods.

Comment: I read up on type hint and stub files now, thanks for your help!